# Watermark video source live

Tags: video, live, watermark, directshow.net, ffdshow

I would like to watermark a video that is taken from for instance a webcam.

in the normal setup you would see this flow
webcam -> capture software

what i would like to do programmatically is to 
webcam -> watermark -> capture software

how does one do this ? is there any frameworks for this?
a requirement is not to capture and then store to disk since this is for a live stream.

also, would there need to another fake camera device to able to pull the signal from the processed watermark output signal?